# Regulations Regarding Artificial Embryos In Space Colonization

Tags: space-colonization

With natural reproduction in space having significant issues and drawbacks, such as the presence of microgravity causing either minor or severe detrimental alterations to human physiology, scientists in many nation's genetic engineering and biological departments have begun to create alternative forms of reproduction allow for the proliferation of the human species throughout space. One of these is the inclusion of artificial embryo "designer" vats where embryos are engineered and designed to adapt to a chosen planet's environment. Naturally, this has led to a prodigious amount of ethical questions as examples of "caste" based societies have developed on multiple planets that have gained independence from state legislation.

The technology is ubiquitous and readily available to anyone willing to colonize a planet, but what would be the possible restrictions revolving around this technology? Governments in this universe are afraid of the almost limitless repercussions involving their use despite being widely deployed, so what restrictions and regulations might be made?

Comment: Welcome MDGouf. It's a great idea and the basis of a rather good question. It is somewhat open-ended and broad at present. Can you help us by narrowing it down. Is there a particular problem or issue you'd like addressing?

Comment: What kind of restrictions are you looking for exactly? Restrictions on the machine itself? Restrictions for living beings having adapted to the specific planet they were planned for? Can you explain a bit more how you see this "create-your-baby" system?

Comment: @Escapeddentalpatient. is correct, this is open-ended and broad, violating the [help/dont-ask]'s book rule. The consequences of this technology go way beyond caste-based societies. From the perspective of the proverbial white supremacist this tech would be used to eliminate the entire LGBT spectrum, all races but one, it might even be used to eliminate all genders but one. The ethics of this kind of tech is a common discussion in Science Fiction. We try not to close new user questions, but Stack Exchange expects *specific problems,* not brainstorming. A list like you're asking would be huge.

Comment: It is unlikely that a civilization like that would have the same moral compass as us. For example, we don't think that taking a picture of someone will capture that persons soul, like some tribes unfamiliar with the technology do. But we do think about privacy concerns, which other cultures perceive differently. What is wrong with creating a planet with only purple people? But more to the point, who is enforcing this and with what means, if they have the means?

Comment: Where are the teachers, where the parents, medics? Who runs the infrastructure until they're all growed up? Are you  cloning minds too, so growing up is purely physical? Is the aim that everyone should be capable of reproduction, or is cloning the way it's done?

Comment: "what would be the possible restrictions revolving around this technology?" This sounds like a prompt for a book, It is a topic that has been covered multiple times...  But this question goes outside of the purpose of worldbuilding which is to help you flesh out world details, not right your book.

Comment: Are you looking for what kind of legal restrictions would evolve around the technology's use, or what kind of physical limits the technology itself has?

Answer (score 1):

First, If your civilization still has some values of "natural" reproduction, they could create a method to rapidly force evolution. Microfluidic lab-on-a-chip combine input streams of male and female gametes, whose DNA is analyzed for compatibility with the chosen planet and then individually combined to create a zygote. Sufficiently advanced chips could churn out zygotes.
Each new Zygote could then be coerced into becoming male and female gametes and fed back into the system, where the process repeats. This could allow hundreds of generations of targeted evolution in months or weeks.
In terms of restrictions, only permitting evolution-based genetic modifications would significantly limit the potential misuse of genetic technologies. New colonists will still be tailored to their new environment but within the constraints of their forefathers genetic information.

Second, if the civilization doesn't value evolution-based adaptations, then true genetic engineering, involving the insertion of any arbitrary gene into a zygote might be considered. The technology would mean that a colonist ship could completely spurn their human form, rapidly speciating into different, likely strictly better, branches of humanity. I don't think a government would like that.
Possible restrictions:

1. Colonists are given government-made genetic processors that restrict colonists to a menu of genes provided by the government.
2. Colonists have hidden genes that the government has pre-modified them with that somehow (handwave) restrict unauthorized genes from being modified into their germlines. Colonists could try to beat those restrictions at their own risk.
3. Government watchdog computers shadow the colonists decisions and report on them.
4. The devices are too cheap and too effective for easy government control. The central gov has to send fleets to rogue colonies of half-humans periodically. The only enforcement is war.

You could